# Python Pandas Pivot Table Error - pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I'm new to pandas and I'm trying to run a pivot table to provide a qty sum per SKU of the following dataframe (named as df):

```
   SKU                           Description       Price  Qty
0  0150JK10F-150-S-RG            Jacket with Logo  14.34    2 
1     0JK10F-150-S-RG                Jacket Plain  14.77    2
2     111118-350-0-RG              Slack - RG Fit  21.82    1
3     111118-350-2-RG              Slack - RG Fit  21.82    2
5  0150JK10F-150-S-RG            Jacket with Logo  14.34   20
```

The idea is that when the pivot table is run, the following would display (i.e. the qtys for the jacket with logo would combine 2 + 20 to make 22):

```
                   SKU                 Description  Price   Qty 
 0  0150JK10F-150-S-RG            Jacket with Logo  14.34    22
 1     0JK10F-150-S-RG                Jacket Plain  14.77     2 
 2     111118-350-0-RG              Slack - RG Fit  21.82     1 
 3     111118-350-2-RG              Slack - RG Fit  21.82     2
```

To try and achieve this, I run the following:

```
        df2 = pd.pivot_table(data=df,  columns=["SKU", "Description", "Price", "Qty"])
        print(df2)
```

However, this results in the following error:

```
       pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

I have checked the data types and the column I want to aggregate (i.e. Qty) is int64, and therefore a numeric field:

```
SKU            object
Description    object
Price          object
Qty             int64
dtype: object
```

Any ideas on why this isn't working? Thanks for any advice.

Comment: try, ``df.groupby(['SKU', 'Description', 'Price'], as_index=False).sum()`` ?

Comment: it's not a `pivot` it's a `groupby()` `agg()`